# Textbox autocomplete not working

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

```
private  void AutoComplete()
{
    textBox4.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    textBox4.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("select ID from Car ", connParam);
    OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder2 = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter2);

    DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    dAdapter2.Fill(dataTable2);
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable2.Rows)
    {
         //TextBox1.Text = row["ImagePath"].ToString();
         col.Add(row["ID"].ToString());
    }
    textBox4.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
}
```

I was calling this function in form load but not working

I also call the method **on text_change** but i faced the same problem that **no values appeared**

Comment: What is not working ? What is the error ?

Comment: textbox4 no showing suggested values

Comment: handler, attached to Form Load event, can silently quit if exception happens in that method. Try to call `AutoComplete()` from another place and check if there are any exceptions.

Comment: i tried call method when text_change but i faced the same problem that no values appeared

Comment: I had the same problem with textbox, for me i was using multiline with textbox which was causing this issue. Changing multiline to false solved the issue.